# Error when creating user from custom model

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm, django-users

I am relatively new to Django, but just finished creating a custom user model rather then using the base. When running createsuperuser im getting the following error stack:

> File "C:\Users\adamt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
> super().save(*args, **kwargs)
> TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

My custom model, `create_user` and `create_superuser` are:

```
    def create_user(self, email, username, FirstName, Surname, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an Email Address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a Username")
        if not FirstName:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a First Name")
        if not Surname:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a Surname")
        
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            FirstName=FirstName,
            Surname=Surname,
            )
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(user=self._db)
        return user
        
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, FirstName, Surname, password):
        user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        FirstName=FirstName,
        Surname=Surname,
        password=password,
        )
            
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        
        user.save(user=self._db)
        return user
        
            
        
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name ="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    DateofBirth = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of Birth")
    MarketingOptIn = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Marketing Opt In", default=False)
    FirstName = models.CharField(verbose_name="First Name", max_length=100)
    Surname = models.CharField(verbose_name="Surname", max_length=100)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username','FirstName','Surname', ]
    
    objects = AccountManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

I have clearly missed something but for the life of me can't see it. Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [**`.save(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) a `Model` object, you can use a `using=…` parameter to specify the database, not <s>`user=…`</s>, so:

```
    def create_user(self, email, username, FirstName, Surname, password=None):
        # …
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
        
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, FirstName, Surname, password):
        # …
        
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the issue. I guess I need to take some time looking at the Docs more.